# Google Apps Script - Delay sending an email by 48 hours

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to delay sending an email by by 48 hours.  I've tried:

```
var mail_date_plus_2 = new Date(date.setDate(mail_date+2))
```

but I get the error:

> "ReferenceError: "date" is not defined. (line 26, file "Code").

Here is the script:

```
function sendEmail() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = data_sheet.getRange(2, 1, data_sheet.getLastRow(), data_sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var row = 2;
  var current_time= new Date();
  Logger.log('Current data and time is '+current_time)
  for(var v in values) {    
    var mail_note = data_sheet.getRange(row, 1).getNote();
    if(mail_note=='') {
      var mail_date = values[v][5];
      if(mail_date!='') {        
        if(current_time>mail_date) {
          Logger.log(v+'>>Need to send mail at '+mail_date);
          var name  =  values[v][2];
          var email =  values[v][4];
          var form  =  values[v][1];
          var htmlbody = RESERVATION_EMAIL_HTML;
          var prefix = 'Dear '+name+', '+"<br/><br/>";
          htmlbody = prefix + htmlbody
          if(form=='Reservation') {MailApp.sendEmail({
             to: email,
             subject: EMAIL_SUBJECT,
             htmlBody: htmlbody,        
          });
          }
          var cdate = new Date();
          data_sheet.getRange(row, 1).setNote('Mail has been sent at '+cdate)
        }
      }
    }
    row++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where `date` is, you need to change it to `mail_date`.  But firest make sure that `mail_date` is a date type.  You can check JavaScript variable types with the key word `typeof`.

```
var mail_date = values[v][5];
Logger.log('typeof mail_date: ' + typeof mail_date);
```

If `mail_date` is not a date type, then convert it to a date:

```
var mail_date = values[v][5];

if (typeof mail_date !== 'object') {//In JavaScript a date is an "object" type
  mail_date = new Date(mail_date);
};

var mail_date_plus_2 = new Date(mail_date.setDate(mail_date+2))
```

Comment: thank you for the response. After the change, I get another error:

TypeError: Cannot find function setDate in object . (line 28, file "Code")